# Dynamically change a Source parameters

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

How I can dynamically change a Source parameters (for example: for a File source - directory)?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

You can host the `file-source` properties in config-server to centrally manage the dynamic changes via git-commit. On a new commit, you could trigger a refresh on the property that you'd like to change dynamically.

With that said, you'd have to customize the [`file-source`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file) to add the `@RefreshScope` annotation, so the `directory` can be changed dynamically.

There are a lot of online postings on config-server and I thought [this article](http://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/) might be useful.